# JSON data to autoTable jsPDF

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

Since few days, I try to find a soluce for my problem :
With help of @Oliver, I get AJAX working. This is my PHP code for get data and return JSON :

```
if (isset($_GET['nexans'])) {

  $nexans = json_decode($_GET['nexans'], true);

  $tab_req = array();


  foreach($nexans as $key => $value) {
    $req_jsonmultipdf = $maPdoFonction - > PDF_Multi($key, $value, $_SESSION['ssetablissement_id'], '4', 'NEXANS');
    $tab_req[] = $req_jsonmultipdf - > fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  }

  $retour = array(
    "success" => true,
    "data" => $tab_req
  );

  header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
  echo json_encode($tab_req);
}
```

Here, no problem. I need to use jsPDF for generate a PDF file. I need too autoTable (plugin for jsPDF if you don't know). In this PDF file, I must insert JSON data in a table with autoTable.

EDIT : This is my JS who generate the [PDF file](https://ufile.io/fab9a) :

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "../modules/ajax/A.php",
      data: {
        'A': _json
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(json) {
          var len = json.length;
          if (len > 0) {

            // Default export is a4 paper, portrait, using milimeters for units
            var pdf = new jsPDF();
            pdf.page = 1;

            var trame_eiffage = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABcAAAGBCAMAAAC6vNp4AAAAIVBMVEWBgYEAAAD/AAAAAAD/AAAAAAD+AAAAAAD+AAAAAAD/AAD1ONESAAAACXRSTlMAERESEu3t7u5UgpEXAAAAVUlEQVR4Ae3UKQ6AUABDwbIv9z8wFlHxE4Kbkc+3ubpPXdePLksXeJu6bJ3d6f4K/6br/g1/pfsrGDJ32bvc3VDX9bPL2gX8m+7f+IEf03U/hn/T9Qd/S7Do6Hk+MwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';
            pdf.addImage(trame_eiffage, 'PNG', 207, 3, 3, 60);

            /* Création de tableau avec des données JSON
                                                            Source : https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable
                                                     */
            var columns = ["Chantier", "Codet", "Désignation", "Q.", "Prix U", "Livraison à", "GPS : Lat.", "GPS : Lon."];

            pdf.autoTable(columns, json, {
              styles: {
                fillColor: [156, 154, 154],
              },
              headerStyles: {
                lineWidth: 0.35,
                lineColor: [0, 0, 0],
                valign: 'middle',
                halign: 'center',
                fontStyle: 'bold'
              },
              bodyStyles: {
                lineWidth: 0.35,
                lineColor: [0, 0, 0]
              },
              margin: {
                horizontal: 0,
                top: 55,
                bottom: 0
              },
              columnStyles: {
                0: {
                  columnWidth: 18,
                  halign: 'middle',
                  fontStyle: 'bold',
                  textColor: [0, 0, 0]
                },
                1: {
                  columnWidth: 17,
                  halign: 'middle',
                  fontStyle: 'bold',
                  textColor: [0, 0, 0]
                },
                2: {
                  columnWidth: 'auto',
                  halign: 'left',
                  fontStyle: 'bold',
                  textColor: [0, 0, 0]
                },
                3: {
                  columnWidth: 8,
                  halign: 'left',
                  fontStyle: 'bold',
                  textColor: [0, 0, 0]
                },
                4: {
                  columnWidth: 13,
                  halign: 'middle',
                  fontStyle: 'bold',
                  textColor: [0, 0, 0]
                },
                5: {
                  columnWidth: 'auto',
                  halign: 'left',
                  fontStyle: 'bold',
                  textColor: [0, 0, 0]
                },
                6: {
                  columnWidth: 'auto',
                  halign: 'left',
                  fontStyle: 'bold',
                  textColor: [0, 0, 0]
                },
                7: {
                  columnWidth: 'auto',
                  halign: 'left',
                  fontStyle: 'bold',
                  textColor: [0, 0, 0]
                }
              },

              showHeader: 'everyPage', // 'everyPage', 'firstPage', 'never',
              tableWidth: 183,
              margin: {
                top: 40,
                right: 13,
                bottom: 0,
                left: 13
              },
              pageBreak: 'auto', // 'auto', 'avoid'
              overflow: 'linebreak' // visible, hidden, ellipsize or linebreak
            });

            function header() {
              /* Encodage en base64 de l'image (obligatoire)
                                                                 Source : https://www.base64encode.org/
                                                            */
              var logo_eiffage = 'data:image/png;base64,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';

              pdf.setFont("helvetica");
              pdf.setFontType("bold");
              pdf.setFontSize(20);
              pdf.text(200, 15, 'DEMANDE D\'ACHAT\r', null, null, 'right');
              pdf.setFontSize(8);
              pdf.setFont("helvetica");
              pdf.text(189, 8, '\r\r\r\rle ' + date_du_jour + ',', null, null, 'right');

              pdf.addImage(logo_eiffage, 'JPEG', 8, 8, 40, 14);
            };
            header();

            pdf.setFontSize(10);
            pdf.setFont("helvetica");
            pdf.setFontType("normal");
            pdf.text(18, 35, 'Voici le récapitulatif de votre demande d\'achat pour le fournisseur ');

            pdf.setFontSize(10);
            pdf.setFont("helvetica");
            pdf.setFontType("bold");
            pdf.text(121, 35, 'X');

            pdf.setFontSize(10);
            pdf.setFont("helvetica");
            pdf.setFontType("normal");
            pdf.text(136, 35, ' : ');

            // then use this as a counter.
            function footer() {
              pdf.setFontSize(8);
              pdf.setFont("helvetica");
              pdf.setFontType("bold");
              pdf.text(150, 285, 'Page ' + pdf.page);
              pdf.page++;
            };
            footer();

            pdf.save('A' + date_du_jour + '.pdf');
```

So, from my AJAX request, I get a array, and in this array, each row who is an array. I search a soluce for parse my JSON, and populate autoTable for create a table so please. If you have idea for help me please. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Have you tried passing the array to autoTable as described in the docs? If you have, can you update the question with the code you tried and any potensial error messages.

Comment: @SimonBengtsson. Works Great ! But on my table, I get [Object object] :/

Comment: Please update your question with the JS that generates PDF with issues.

Comment: @Purushoth : I have edited my post thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUCE :
1- Make AJAX request and return JSON
2- In your success in AJAX, parse JSON data like this :

```
var rows = [];
                                                                                                jQuery(json).each(function(i, item){ // FOR EACH ROW
                                                                                                    jQuery(item).each(function(i, item){ // EACH VALUE IN THE ROW -> INSERT DATA IN AN ARRAY WHO WILL BE USED BY JSPDF AUTOTABLE LATER
                                                                                                        rows.push([
                                                                                                            item.chantier_ref, item.article_codet, item.description, item.quantite, item.prixU_commande+' €', item.livraison_add1 +' '+item.livraison_add2 +' '+item.livraison_add3 + item.livraison_cp +' '+item.livraison_ville, item.livraison_gps_lat+' °C', item.livraison_gps_lon+' °C'
                                                                                                        ]);
                                                                                                    });
                                                                                                });
```